# How to correctly create an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I wanna make an array look like this.
Please have a look and compare the code so you'll directly get what I means.

```
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => array(
                1, 2, 3
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                /*
                array(
                    'key' => 'year',
                    'value' => '2014',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'year',
                    'value' => '2013',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
                */
                $getarray
            ),
            'suppress_filters' => false
        );
```

But when I do this, I still get the numbered output:

```
                array_push(
                    $getarray,
                    array(
                        'key' => 'organization_type',
                        'value' => $val,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                );
```

Var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(17) "organization_type" ["value"]=> string(10) "foundation" ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" } }
```

How can I make an array to contain arrays like:

```
                array(
                    'key' => 'year',
                    'value' => '2014',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'year',
                    'value' => '2013',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
```

Comment: If you don't understand arrays, don't start with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: The question is very unclear. You seem to be asking how to do what you already know how to do. You say `"How can I make an array to contain arrays like:"` and then give the very syntax needed for that. So I don't get it. Only thing I can figure is you haven't mastered 2d arrays yet and so are confused by multidimensional arrays.  Well, the only solution is to master 2d arrays first, and to understand the difference between using numerical indexes and associative indexes.

Comment: Even so, I will post an answer that I guess is what you mean.

Comment: Values in arrays must have a corresponding key.  You can ignore them if you want, but they HAVE to be there, it's a fundamental part of what arrays in PHP are.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for?

```
$array = array();
$array['key'] = "year";
$array['value'] = "2014";
$array['compare'] = "LIKE";
foreach($array as $i){
   echo "$i";
}
```

Comment: Not really. I just wanna make an array in an Foreach that contains several arrays without index!

Comment: soo you can make a foreach($i as $j), on the middle of foreach($Array as $i) that will probably work if u have and array inside another array

Comment: `code` foreach($Array as $i){
   foreach($i as $j){
    echo "Array $i => $j";
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of guesswork, I figure you are asking how to put:

```
            array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2014',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2013',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
```

into another array using associative indexes (i.e. words rather than numbers).  It would look something like this:

```
array(
      'array1' => array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2014',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
      'array2' =>  array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2013',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
);
```

In other words, you have to specify the word you want to use as an index.  You could also do it like:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['array1'] = array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2014',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
$arr['array2'] = array(
                'key' => 'year',
                'value' => '2013',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
```

Comment: Wow,  had a massive formatting mistake, but all fixed now.

Comment: Exactly! How to do it?

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I don't want to have an array with keys. It should just contain the value without key. :(

Comment: @Maxi, Then it wouldn't be an array. Like I said initially in the comments on the question, you are confused on even basic 2d arrays.  Arrays have keys: that's what they are. If they didn't, they'd be worthless.